# Is "any" used with a plural countable noun in a prepositional phrase of a negative sentence?

Tags: word-usage

Textbooks tell us that "any" is often used with a plural countable noun in a negative sentence. For example,

> (1) I don't have any apples.

> (2) I can't come up with any ideas.

Does that apply to a countable noun in a prepositional phrase?

> (3) She and I broke up. I can't go to her house for any **reasons**.

> (4) I don't want to upset him. I won't give up on the project for any **reasons**.

Comment: In sentences like that we would say 'for any reason' (singular). Here,  'any' means 'no matter what'.

Comment: See my answer, and the ensuing discussion in comments, to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/564216/when-do-we-use-any-with-countable-nouns/564219?noredirect=1#comment1396700_564219)